# Difference of UML Aggregation with and without arrow head

Tags: uml, aggregation, class-diagram

Note: This is not the duplicate of [uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head) but the improved and rectified version of it!

In [uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head), **aggregation** was explained as a **black FILLED diamond**. That is obviously **WRONG** as a FILLED diamond is a composition. Until now I haven't seen the composition with arrow head, so my question is in the context of **aggregation**

Motivation of my question came from the **[Gof23](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)**. The class diagram in that book contains the aggregation with arrow head. So I am very confused about it as I usually only use the aggregation without arrow head

**Question:** What is the difference between **aggregation with an arrow head** `<>----->` and **aggregation without arrow head**`<>-----`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation and navigability at the same end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855657/aggregation-and-navigability-at-the-same-end)

Comment: This is still a duplicate. The answer provided to the other question remains valid for this one as it clearly indicates "**any** association". It doesn't matter if you have shared or composite aggregation. Also in a new version of the specification terms `shared aggregation` and `composite aggregation` are preferred over older terms `aggregation` and `composition`. So a reference to aggregation covers both cases and aggregation is depicted in general with a diamond, while hollow or filled indicates only if the aggregation is shared or composite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML Aggregation with and without arrow head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is the same as my answer to the question

> What is the difference between *composition* with an arrow head `<>----->` and *composition* without arrow head `<>-----`?

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767999/2795909, except that you have to replace the solid diamond (for *composition*) with the hollow diamond (for *aggregation*).

Since you ask about the use of the navigability arrow, the answer does not depend on the kind of association (plain, aggregate, composite). So, you could also entirely drop the diamond and ask

> What is the difference between *association* with an arrow head `----->` and *association* without arrow head `-----`?

and still get the same answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remind :) That answer indeed explained my confusion