# arrow to diamond, is this a aggregation ot that?

Tags: uml

remarked this type of releationship, arrow to diamons that is this?
Is this a simply association or what?[part of diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRFp9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation and navigability at the same end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855657/aggregation-and-navigability-at-the-same-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hollow diamond depicts shared aggregation (the diamond is on the "whole" side).

An arrow depicts a navigability so it shows that the part is "aware" of a whole.